# XNA Timer keeps going up instead of down

Tags: c#, xna

I created a timer watching a video on youtube.

I am unable to get it to go down instead of up.

This is the code which is placed within the update method:

```
 _timer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```

This is the draw code:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(_FirstFont, ((int)_timer / 1000).ToString(), _vec, Color.White);
```

Is there a reason why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried `_timer -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;`? Also, what is your timer? A stopwatch?

Comment: @davidsbro My time is suppose to countdown from 2mins/ 120secs. couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Yeah, but what's your timer (a stopwatch for example), and have you tried -= instead of +=?

Comment: @davidsbro it's suppose to countdown to the end of my quiz game.

Comment: @davidsbro. Is there a way of adding an if statement to that so it changes to the next state? Also how do I set the countdown to start from 120secs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on the question, but I think I know what you're trying to do. If you want a timer to count down in milliseconds, you could try something like this:

```
int countdown;

public void Initialize()
{
    countdown = 120000; //120 seconds
}

public override void Update()
{
    countdown -= gameTime.ElapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Draw:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(_FirstFont, ((int)_timer / 1000).ToString(), _vec, Color.White);
```

hope this helps